# How do I sum the elements of an arbitrary number of arrays with different lengths in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

While the code below will satisfy adding two arrays with different lengths, how can I modify this to accept an arbitrary number of arrays as arguments so that, for example, ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]) will return an array of [11, 7, 3] ?

```
const addTogether = (arr1, arr2) => {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length); i++) {
    result.push((arr1[i] || 0) + (arr2[i] || 0))

  }
  return result
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested array, and loop over the array rather than hard-coding two array variables.

You can use `arrays.map()` to get all the lengths so you can calculate the maximum length. And `arrays.reduce()` to sum up an element in each array.

```js
const addTogether = (...arrays) => {
  let result = [];
  let len = Math.max(...arrays.map(a => a.length));
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    result.push(arrays.reduce((sum, arr) => sum + (arr[i] || 0), 0));
  }
  return result
}

console.log(addTogether([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `for` loop that requires you to know the lengths of each array, try using something that doesn't. For example - `while` loop.

Increment using a dummy variable and reset it for each array and set condition for loop termination as - `arr[i] === null`.

Comment: If you click `[<>]` you can actually show an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object inside function.

> `arguments` is an Array-like object accessible inside functions that contains the values of the arguments passed to that function.

```js
const addTogether = function () {
  const inputs = [...arguments];
  const maxLen = Math.max(...inputs.map((item) => item.length));
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < maxLen; i ++) {
    result.push(inputs.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + (cur[i] || 0), 0));
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(addTogether([1,2,3], [4,5], [6]));
```

Comment: If you're using ES6 you can use `...inputs` in the parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```js
const addTogether = (...args) => {
let result = [];
let max = 0;
args.forEach((arg)=>{
    max = Math.max(max,arg.length)
})
for(let j=0;j<max;j++){
result[j]= 0
for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
   if(args[i][j])
     result[j]+= args[i][j]
     }
  }
  return result
 }
 console.log(addTogether([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]))
```

Output:[ 11, 7, 3 ]

Answer (score 0):

Use `rest param syntax` to accept an arbitrary number of arguments. Sort the outer array by their length in descending order. By using destructuring assignment separate the first and rest of the inner arrays. At last use `Array.prototype.map()` to traverse the first array as it is the largest array and use `Array.prototype.reduce()` method to get the summation.

```js
const addTogether = (...ar) => {
  ar.sort((x, y) => y.length - x.length);
  const [first, ...br] = ar;
  return first.map(
    (x, i) => x + br.reduce((p, c) => (i < c.length ? c[i] + p : p), 0)
  );
};

console.log(addTogether([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]));
```